# How to truncate log files older than 14 days?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron, truncate

How to truncate the active log file older than 2 weeks?

I tried with the following command and it is not working

```
find . -name '*.log'  -type f  -mtime +14  -exec truncate -s 0 "{}" \;
```

Comment: file older than 2 weeks or file content older than two weeks?

Comment: what does "active" mean? is another process still holding the logfile open and writing to it?

Comment: content older than 2 weeks in a log file

Comment: what does "active" mean? is another process still holding the logfile open and writing to it?

---- i referred for running service